# Is there a way to specify an order of toolbars using Mozilla add-on sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

Our app is using 1+ toolbars written using add-on sdk.  The problem is, right now the toolbars seems to decide for themselves in which order they will get displayed.  In the first window I have toolbar A below toolbar B.  However, if I open a new window, toolbar B will be on top.

Anybody else encountered this issue?  Do you guys have any tips on how to deal with it?

Thanks!
Luka

EDIT: attaching a code that shows how I create toolbars:

```
    this.myframe = new ui.Frame({
        url: self.data.url(this.LABELS.TRANSLATION_FRAME)
    });

    this.mytoolbar = ui.Toolbar({
        title: this.NAME,
        items: [this.myframe],
        hidden: true
    });
```

The second toolbar has the same three arguments (title, items, hidden) and both frames contain a properly structured, very minimal html files.

These toolbars reside in two separate extensions.  If both are enabled, as I mentioned above, the ordering seems to be pretty random.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you use to create your toolbars. It is *much* easier to provide relevant answers if you provide us somewhere to start. This helps everyone stay focused, and be talking about the same thing. With questions like this, it is common to want to play around with code prior to answering (to verify one is providing a good answer) unless someone happens to have encountered the exact issue. Without code it makes the barrier to providing a good answer much higher. Thus, you get fewer, or no, answers which tend, on average, not to be as high quality.

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I see you added code to your post; did you ever find a solution?